# check date validation with greater than today's date along with date format in js

Tags: javascript, validation, date

How to validate the date in terms of 'dd-mm-yyyy H:i:s ' format and that date should be greater than system's date and time. This validation should be in javascript.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually I was trying to check the number of '-' first if its 2 then go  for timing. Again split day, year month and calculating with today's date. But its  huge process, that's why I asked, is there any shortest process? If so please give a guide. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Niels 's logic is right but the function he had written is incorrect.
`parseDate` is not returning correct value. you can check both values here. **[Niel's Fiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/7jrQZ/75/)**

Here is the correct function : **[correct fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7jrQZ/76/)**

```
function parseDate(str)
{
    var s = str.split(" "),
        d = s[0].split("-"),
        t = s[1].replace(/:/g, "");
    return d[2] + d[1] + d[0] + t;
}

if( parseDate("17-05-1989 12:15:00") > parseDate("15-05-1989 14:00:00") )
{
    alert("larger");
}
else
{
   alert("smaller");  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this for example (live Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7jrQZ/):

```
function parseDate(str)
{
    var s = str.split(" "),
        d = str[0].split("-"),
        t = str[1].replace(/:/g, "");
    return d[2] + d[1] + d[0] + t;
}

if( parseDate("17-05-1989 12:15:00") > parseDate("15-05-1989 14:00:00") )
{
    alert("larger")
}
else
{
   alert("smaller")   
}
```

Comment: Please mark it as the correct answer if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Actually on that time I was unable to mark it as a correct answer. Anyway thanks once again.

Comment: you have not write proper function, Its incorrect.. Also don't know why @Srim have mark as answer without check... check this : http://jsfiddle.net/7jrQZ/75/